# how to display picture from data base? if i try to display it. it only shows the name of the image

Tags: php, mysql, database

[image]

here's my code i tried to use the base64 but the same problem occurs the img is already saved in my server/folder

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM prods";
$result  = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


  echo "<table border='2'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Photo</th><th>Stocks</th></tr>";
 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["prodName"]."</td><td>" . $row["prodPrice"]. "</td><td>" . $row["prodPic"]
        /*'<img src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($row["prodPic"]).'" alt="Image" style="width: 10px; height: 10px;" >';*/."</td><td>" . $row["prodQuant"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";  

    }


?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form action="up.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name">
            <input type="text" name="fileTitle" placeholder="Image Name">
            <input type="text" name="fileDesc" placeholder="Price">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <button type="submit" name="submit"> Upload </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to write `<img src='" . $row["prodName"]."'>`, so that the link points to the file on the server. If the image is on the server disk then I don't think base64 needs to be involved.

Comment: BTW the base64 is comment

Comment: I know that, but you don't have an alternative img tag either. You need one, if you want to display the image. Did you try what I suggested above? You might need to add a folder before the filename if you have them stored in a subfolder below where your PHP script is stored.

Comment: yes i already tried just a icon unload picture i don't know what's that called. still it wont display image.:\xampp\htdocs\OVS\img(where the image is stored)

Comment: is your PHP script stored in htdocs? In that case as I already noted, you'll need to specify the (relative) path to the image. e.g. something like `<img src='OVS/img/" . $row["prodName"]."'>` perhaps. (The objective, remember, is to form a valid URL to the image file, which the browser will then use to download it and display it in the `img` tag. If you open your browser's Network tool and then load your page, you'll see a request being logged going to the URL in your img tag. You can check there if the URL looks correct and what status code it returns.)

Comment: '<img src="../ovs/<?php echo $row["prodPic"];?>' this one? no img name just an icon of unload img but still not display [https://prnt.sc/11sxgmd] [link](https://prnt.sc/11sxgmd)

Comment: Check the path then. As I said, I _assumed_ your PHP script is stored in htdocs, but I don't know that for sure. You need to put some effort into figuring this out yourself as well, because we don't have all the necessary information.

Comment: From the picture, it looks like maybe the PHP file is stored in `ovs`? In that case, the path to the image should probably be `img/` i.e the tag would be `<img src='img/" . $row["prodName"]."'>`, as that would be the relative path from ovs to img. Again, check the URL the browser is actually calling, and see if it corresponds to the folder setup in the webserver. (If you used `../ovs/` as the path, then relative to starting from the "ovs" folder, it will go up one level, and then go back to "ovs". In other words, it points to itself!)

Comment: xampp\htdocs\OVS\img the path 
img where the images is stored and ovs where the php is stored also i try '<img src="img/<?php echo $row["prodPic"];?>' ../img/ , /img/ still just unload images icon. still im figuring this out watching tutorials still all i've seen don't work. pls be don't hard on me i'm still beginner of this :)

Comment: I'm not being hard on you. You need to be able to understand how relative paths work, it's a pretty fundamental thing. Asking you to make some effort to understand and investigate is not a harsh thing to do! I'm helping as much as I can, but I can't see your machine or your disk. Also, have you yet opened your Developer Tools as I suggested, gone to the Network tool and seen what request is actually being made to load the image, and what status code you get back? From what you've said I'd expect `<img src='img/" . $row["prodPic"]."'>` to work...check the Network in case there is another issue

Comment: [https://prnt.sc/11t0s32] you mean this one? sorry i don't know about developer tools

Comment: Yes that one. Clearly from the picture it is accessing a nonsense URL - the bit highlighted in red. Looks like you tried to embed a PHP echo command inside another PHP string. That isn't going to work! Try it exactly like I suggested: `<img src='img/".$row["prodPic"]."'>` . (I'm assuming that this code is already within the echo command which starts with `echo "<tr><td>....`).

Comment: OH THANK YOU SO MUCH I FINALLY GOT IT. i just added "<img src='img/" . $row["prodPic"]."'>" the double quotation mark to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
"<img src='img/" . $row["prodPic"]."'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I assume `$row['prodPic']` is a `string` containing a relative path to an image file.

If that's the case, first you need the base directory in which you are saving all those images (assuming that you are saving them somewhere). Let's say that directory is `/var/www/app/uploads` and that exists in a variable called `$uploadsDir`.

Then, in the line where you have your `base64_encode` you should call `base64_encode(file_get_contents($uploadsDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$row["prodPic"])`

Now, that is the easiest way to accomplish what you want, but it's a terrible one. Base64 inlined images make your document really heavy. It's better if you provide links to another script that will give your application the image. The browser will handle the image retrieval for you.

Comment: prodPic is the database column where the image is stored.

Comment: Not quite sure about that. Given the code and the image, it is not storing the actual image but the path to the image.